# Makefile rule only works if file exists before make is invoked

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a) `Makefile`:

```
my_target: prepare test.bin

prepare:
    echo >test.dat

%.bin: %.dat
    cp $? $@
```

If you run `make` in a clean directory, it fails:

```
echo >test.dat
make: *** No rule to make target 'test.bin', needed by 'my_target'. Stop.
```

Run it again and it succeeds:

```
echo >test.dat
cp test.dat test.bin
```

What seems to happen is that the rule to make `*.bin` from `*.dat` only recognises that it knows how to make `test.bin` *if `test.dat` exists before anything is executed*, even though according to the output it has already created `test.dat` before it tries to create `test.bin`.

This is inconvenient for me as I have to prepare a few files first (import them from a different, earlier part of the build).

Is there a solution?  Perhaps some way to allow the rules to be (re)evaluated in the light of the files which are now present?

Comment: Create a target `test.dat` which creates the file and let `prepare` depend on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your makefile.  However based on your comments I'm inclined to assume that the MCVE here is just a little *too* "M" and it's been reduced so much that it has a number of basic problems.  So I won't discuss them, unless you want me to.

The issue here is that you're creating important files without indicating to make that that's what you're doing.  Make keeps internally a cache of the contents of directories that it's worked with, for performance reasons, and that cache is only updated when make invokes a rule that it understands will modify it.

Here your target is `prepare` but the recipe actually creates a completely different file, `test.dat`.  So, make doesn't modify its internal cache of the directory contents and when it checks the cache to see if the file `test.dat` exists, it doesn't.

You need to be sure that your makefile is written such that it doesn't trick make: if a recipe creates a file `foo` then the target name should be `foo`, not `bar`.

Comment: Thanks - this answer highlighted the problem: _you're creating important files without indicating to make that that's what you're doing_.  The solution was to create a rule whose purpose is to create the required files, rather than doing it as a side-effect of another rule. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This happens for wildcard targets, like `%.bin`. They get evaluated at the first pass. You could add an explicit target of **test.bin**. Or, follow the advice of [**tkausl**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl) and have **test.dat** depend on **prepare** (a phony target). In this case, you don't need the double dependency anymore:

```
my_target: test.bin
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I may have over-simplified the problem.  In reality the final build product depends upon many files which need to be copied in, then processed in a few steps, then finally linked together. The problem I was having boils down to this wildcard target thing, which happens at a stage in the middle of all this, but I'm not sure how to generalise your answer to the real problem. I'll have another play with it tomorrow and edit my question if I can represent the problem in a sensible way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
test.dat:  prepare
```

or (when when you want to stay with wildcards)

```
%.dat: prepare
    @:
```

Usually, you might want to create and use `.stamp` files instead of a `prepare` target.